# don´t display a jquery dialog if the dialog have no content

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, dialog

my problem is Im trying to catch automatically flash messages to a jquery dialog but the dialog always is displayed even if there are no flash messages, so the dialog window appears in blank, how can I prevent the dialog appears if there are no flash messages to be displayed. tnks
this is my js code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$( "#notice" ).dialog({ modal: true });});
```

this is the code in my application.html.erb

```
<div id="notice">
    <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
        <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

this is a part of the whole login implementation using bcrypt, see the railscast #250 Authentication from Scratch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could can add that conditionally add the end of your layout or template.

#### application.html.erb

```
<% if !flash.empty? %>
  $("#notice").dialog({ modal: true });});
<% end %>
```